# Error while creating a database in ibm db2

Tags: sql, db2

I installed the IBM DB2 software on my laptop (Windows 10) and the installation is successful.

But when I opened the db2 command windows and I typed:

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2sampl"
```

I get an error like this:

> Attempt to initialize application failed.
> 'db2sampl' processing complete.

and I have been stuck with this problem for hours.

Answer (score 0):

are you running the command with correct user privileges? Log in with the user you created during installation, (for example, db2admin or users belonging to the DB2USERS/DB2ADMNS group) and then try the db2sampl command again.

Answer (score 0):

As Robina said, you should change to the user you created during the installation as it has SYSADM privilege. Since you are trying to run "db2sampl" via command prompt, you can open it with the user created before (db2admin is the default user).

So, you hold SHIFT and right click on command prompt/DB2 CLP shortcut or executable file and then "Run as different user".

You should be able to run "db2sampl" now.